# Nested Switches with Siblings in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm running into an issue with react-router.

I have some routes that display a navbar and some that don't, so I created a parent component where I can pass in a prop deciding if I should show the navbar or not.

The expected behavior is that it will go down the routes in order looking for a route that matches in the first Master component and if that doesn't work, then keep going to the next where I actually catch it and redirect to a 404.

What's actually happening is the first one Master component always renders and I get either the Master without navbar heading if I'm at /no_bar and otherwise nothing.

```
   private routes = (
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path={login} component={Login}/>
         <Route exact path={logout} component={Logout}/>
         <Route exact path={register} component={Register}/>
         <MasterWrapperContainer>
            <Switch>
               <Master>
                  <Switch>
                     <PrivateRoute exact path="/no_bar" component={() => <h2>Master without navbar!</h2>} />
                     <PrivateRoute exact path="/different_no_bar" component={() => <h2>Another route without navbar!</h2>} />
                     <PrivateRoute exact path="/no_bar3" component={() => <h2>Yet another Master without navbar!</h2>} />
                  </Switch>
               </Master>
               <Master navbar>
                  <Switch>
                     <PrivateRoute exact path={joinCourse} component={props => <JoinCourseContainer {...props} />}/>
                     <PrivateRoute exact path={settings} component={UserSettingsContainer} />
                     <PrivateRoute exact path={forbidden} component={ErrorDisplay} />
                     <PrivateRoute exact path={notFound} component={ErrorDisplay} />
                     <PrivateRoute exact path={serverError} component={ErrorDisplay} />
                     <Redirect from="*" to={notFound} />
                  </Switch>
               </Master>
            </Switch>
         </MasterWrapperContainer>
      </Switch>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `Switch` is such that it renders the first matching Route if it wraps a collection of Route and if the component is rendered directly it just renders the first component and stops after that. You need to restructure your code like

```js
<MasterWrapperContainer>
       <Route exact path="/no_bar" render={() => (
         <Master>
           <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/no_bar" component={() => <h2>Master without navbar!</h2>} />
           </Switch>
         </Master>
       )} />
       <Master navbar>
          <Switch>
             <PrivateRoute exact path={joinCourse} component={props => <JoinCourseContainer {...props} />}/>
             <PrivateRoute exact path={settings} component={UserSettingsContainer} />
             <PrivateRoute exact path={forbidden} component={ErrorDisplay} />
             <PrivateRoute exact path={notFound} component={ErrorDisplay} />
             <PrivateRoute exact path={serverError} component={ErrorDisplay} />
             <Redirect from="*" to={notFound} />
          </Switch>
       </Master>
 </MasterWrapperContainer>
```

Comment: So what if I were to have a bunch of routes in the master without a navbar? I updated my example to better clarify the problem.